# React Native Expo: No vertical scrolling on iOS

Tags: ios, reactjs, scroll, expo

#### Back-story

I started developing a simple app with Expo and already implemented some basic features (authentication with Firebase, image resizing/upload to Firestore, etc.).
I realized only much later that **nowhere in the app I can scroll vertically** if the content is longer than the screen. When I tried simplifying the problem I realized that **even in the very initial Expo app I cannot scroll**. So, apparently I am doing something fundamentally wrong but I wasn't able to find out what the issue is.

### Problem

Not able to scroll vertically anywhere in the Expo app (40.0.0) on iOS 14.4.2

### Reproducing the problem

I can reproduce my problem by just setting up a new Expo app with the following command:

```
expo init scrolltest
cd scrolltest
expo start
```

Even if the only thing I do is adding more lines until the screen becomes to small, I cannot scroll on my iOS mobile phone. So, it is basically the following code that doesn't show any scroll functionality.

### Resulting code that is not working (i.e., does not allow scrolling vertically)

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>Open up App.js to start working on your app!</Text>
      [... repeating this line until screen height is exceeded...]
      <Text>Open up App.js to start working on your app!</Text>
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    
  },
});
```

**Dependencies**

```
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "expo": "~40.0.0",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.0.3",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "16.13.1",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-40.0.1.tar.gz",
    "react-native-web": "~0.13.12"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.9.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you haven't stumpled upon the answer already..

You need to import and use `ScrollView` instead of the main `View` that wraps that screen. Or it can be nested inside the main `View` if you have a header or something you want to be static.

See https://reactnative.dev/docs/scrollview

```js
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, ScrollView } from 'react-native';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <ScrollView style={styles.container}>
      <Text>Open up App.js to start working on your app!</Text>
      [... repeating this line until screen height is exceeded...]
      <Text>Open up App.js to start working on your app!</Text>
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
    </ScrollView>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    
  },
});
```

Comment: That did the trick! Thanks a lot!
Just to add: the styles container will not work like in the snippet above due to the "alignItems" and "justifyContent". Instead a nested <View> needs to be added for those options (as Dehn already suggested)